# php - check difference on dates + additional time

Tags: php, date

What would be a good way to check if point is between `start` and `extra`.

```
point = 2010-06-20 
start = 2010-06-17
extra = start + "1 week"
```

Any ideas would be appreciate it.

Comment: shouldn't `extra` be `start + one week`? otherwise, checking if `point` is before `extra` is completely senseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [strtotime](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) - an then simply compare the resulting timestamps:

```
$start = strtotime('2010-06-20');
$point = strtotime('2010-06-17');
$extra = strtotime('+1 week', $start);

if($start < $point && $extra > $point){
  // it's bewtween...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Requires PHP 5.3

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2010-06-17'),
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day'),
    new DateTime('2010-06-17 +1 week')
);

if (in_array(new DateTime('2010-06-20'), iterator_to_array($period))) {
    // date is in range
}
```

Manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php

---

I'd probably extend the `DatePeriod` class to have a `contains` methods:

```
class DateRange extends DatePeriod
{
    public function contains(DateTime $dateTime)
    {
        return in_array($dateTime, iterator_to_array($this));
    }
}
```

then you can do

```
$period = new DateRange(
    new DateTime('2010-06-17'),
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day'),
    new DateTime('2010-06-17 +1 week')
);
if ($period->contains(new DateTime('2011-06-20'))) {
    // date is in range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$start_timestamp = strtotime('2010-05-17');
$end_timestamp   = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $start_timestamp) . " +1 week");
$point_timestamp = strtotime('2010-16-20');

if ($point_timestamp < $end_timestamp && $point_timestamp > $point_timestamp) {
// Do your work
}
```